# Download questions or chats for offline reading

Tags: discussion

Is it allowed to download mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions or chats for offline reading?

If so, how could that be done automatically with Mathematica code?

Comment: Related Meta.SE post: [Stack Exchange Data Explorer and Stack Exchange Data Dumps should include public chat room messages](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/269745/178179)

Answer (score 9):

There is a [link](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) to the content license at the bottom of every page.

There is a sanctioned "data dump" at https://archive.org/details/stackexchange

You can download the file for Mathematica at https://archive.org/download/stackexchange/mathematica.stackexchange.com.7z

See also https://data.stackexchange.com

Comment: Very interesing. Is there something similar for the chat ?

Comment: Not that I am aware of. @andre

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it is permitted. But why write Mathematica code to do it? Why not just use tools provided by your internet browser. AFAIK every browser has such tools. I use Safari on OS X and it certainly does because I quite often use them.

Are you considering something like scraping the whole site on a daily basis?

Comment: I wrote a SE API connection in Mathematica so I can get question info and such automatically and I needed import tools so I could pull down page info. It's also useful when people have dumped info in an answer, such as the ones on FE tokens. In terms of automatically trawling the site, I can see the use for chat rooms and things which update often (and have actually written some of that code too).

Answer (score 4):

I've created a prerelease alpha SE paclet that can be used to view a Stack Exchange question. It is located at:

https://github.com/carlwoll/Stack-Exchange-Stylesheet/releases/tag/v0.1-alpha

Download the .paclet file, and then run:

```
PacletInstall[file]
```

To use, do:

```
<<StackExchange`
StackExchangeView["http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/124583/is-anonymous-pure-function-a-scoping-construct#140256"]
```

It is also possible to use style key tabbing (tab at the start of a cell), shift-enter and right click to modify "StackExchange" styled cells to a markdown version, a hybrid WYSIWIG version, or a deployed version. Feed back is welcomed.

Comment: Very fun. I think WRI should really write a general `XMLObject` to `Notebook` converter (I say this because I notice the headers in, e.g., [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users) don't actually get handled). Also I wrote a general SE api connection in Mathematica code if you want to look at that to potentially stick in the paclet.