# MSE Cloud account / Migrating Tutorials to the Cloud

Tags: discussion, feature-request

So [the common pitfalls question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users) recently floated back up the top of the question list and in looking through it I was struck by how useful it would be to have a lot of this in [the cloud](https://www.wolframcloud.com/) so people could play with it right then and there (albeit much more slowly than on the desktop).

And using [Carl Woll's question-to-notebook converter](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2123/38205) this should honestly not be tough to do, e.g. we could just run a quick

```
CloudDeploy[
 StackExchangeView[
  "https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-\
most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users"], 
 URLParse["https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-\
are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users"
    ]["Path"][[-1]],
 Permissions -> "Public",
 AutoCopy -> True]
```

We'd have to pull in his stylesheet and whatnot, but again, not tough to do.

This could also be used to allow for rather more sophisticated answers when we have tutorial like questions, as more code could be provided without much of a corresponding decay in utility.

Obviously, though, this would involve things like setting up an SE cloud account and some criteria for what should be migrated and what shouldn't, etc.

So there are, I guess, three points of discussion here:

1. Do other people think this is worth setting up?
2. If so, should we have a few primary moderators or should it be an open account? I'd lean towards the former, as the restrictions on free accounts are pretty strict I think and we'd want to make sure only quality stuff got migrated, but that's also sorta against the spirit of MSE.
3. Would anyone want to set this up? (I would be fine with doing so -- I was thinking I'd just make an SE gmail and bind the account to that -- but I'm happy if someone else wants to)

Comment: Who's going to pay for $CloudCredits, or did I miss the concept? What do you mean by migrate?, I don't think that removing anything from mma.se is an option. While interesting I think it will be easier to just put a 'how to: fetch and play' section in the question.

Comment: @Kuba I have a free cloud account that's just bound to a gmail. I mean we may run out for evaluating or something, I don't really know how that works. I didn't mean migrate as in remove, I meant migrate as in also provide a link to the cloud notebook.

Comment: I may got lost in recent updates/changes in WRI products but I think a limited `$CloudCreditsAvailable` is a serious problem here.

Comment: @Kuba entirely possible this isn't feasible. Looking [here](https://billing.wolfram.com/pricing/wpc) the free version does seem to be pretty restricted. It works for me when I need to share code, but you're probably right that it won't work for something as large as MSE.